# Send text file to distant server in Android

Tags: android, apache-httpcomponents

I am trying to send a file from an android phone to a distant server. This is the code I used:

```
    public void sendFile() {
    try {
        // HttpClient
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        // post header
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://example.com/get_data.php");
        // add your data
        MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
        builder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);


        File folder = this.mContext.getFilesDir();
        File file = new File(folder, "test.txt");
        if (file.exists()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "File exists : " + folder.listFiles()[0].toString());
        }
        builder.addPart("file", new FileBody(file));
        builder.addBinaryBody("file", file);

        HttpEntity entity = builder.build();
        post.setEntity(entity);
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
        HttpEntity Httpentity = response.getEntity();

        Log.v("result", EntityUtils.toString(Httpentity));

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

This code should be correct since I found similar examples here and there. The problem occurs when I build the MultipartEntityBuilder:

```
HttpEntity entity = builder.build();
```

I get this error:

> ```
>  Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/apache/http/util/Args;
>         at org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.AbstractContentBody.<init>(AbstractContentBody.java:48)
>         at org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.FileBody.<init>(FileBody.java:96)
>         at org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntityBuilder.addBinaryBody(MultipartEntityBuilder.java:141)
>         at org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntityBuilder.addBinaryBody(MultipartEntityBuilder.java:146)
>         at com.example.kevin.recordacceleration.Accelerometer.sendFile(Accelerometer.java:149)
> ```

The file I'm trying to send is in the internal memory, and I check its existence: it exists.

Here are the libraries that I added:
[image: Libraries .jar]

It is not the latest version because I read on an other topic that this version of httpmime and httpclient should work

Comment: Can you say exactly why you can't use the default implementation of Apache HttpClient that comes with Android?  I don't think you can simply provide your own implementation of HttpClient and expect it to replace the platform version.  (Furthermore, use of HttpClient in Android is deprecated and you should be using URLConnection instead, or a different third party HTTP library like OKHTTP.)

Answer (score 0):

Your app is missing commons-codec and commons-logging on which HttpCore and HttpClient depends. Httpmime depends on HttpClient.